# How do I change column types conditionally between dataframes in a list?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes called `all_input`. Each one of these dataframes has a column called `total_emissions`. In most of these dataframes, the column type is `double` but for some it is `factor`.

Ideally, I want to use a `loop` or `lapply` to go through the list of dataframes, see if the `total_emissions` column is `double`, and if it is not, change it to `double`.

I think an if_else statement could work well for this: if total_emissions column type != double, change it to double, else do nothing. Just not sure how to actually write this process in code.

Comment: How about `lapply(all_input, function(x){if(!is.double(x$total_emissions)){x$total_emissions <- as.double(as.character(x$total_emissions))}; x})`

Comment: @IanCampbell Totally, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

i know this is already answered, but i still wanted to share my code, if anyone comes by this page again and want a fast reproducible example

```
#dummy data
df1 <- mtcars
df2 <- mtcars
df1$mpg <- as.factor(df1$mpg)
df_List <- list(df1,df2)

#code
unfactor <- function(x) {
  if(is.factor(x[,1])){
    x[,1] <- as.numeric(levels(x[,1])[x[,1]])
  }
  return(x)
}

out <- lapply(df_List, unfactor)

#output
str(out)
```